# DELETE function in express.js (MYSQL) not deleting rows

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm setting up a website, and the back-end uses express.js to send queries to a mySQL Database, however, when I try to delete rows, nothing happens.

```
function getConnection() {
  return mysql.createConnection({
    multipleStatements: true,
    host: 'MY HOST',
    user: "USERNAME",
    password: "PSSWD",
    database: "DATABASE"
  })
} 

const queryString = 'DELETE FROM table WHERE Date ="210,2019"; INSERT INTO tables(currentDate, data) Values ?;'
    getConnection().query(queryString, [result], function (err, results, fields) {
    if(err) { console.log(err) }
}
```

I am not getting an error message, and the table only has rows added none removed, even though the date is correct.

Comment: So in your table, in the `Date` column, it literally says `todays date` in some rows...?

Comment: `Date ="todays date";`  you didn't mean `Date = CurDate()` did you.?

Comment: its the current date in the format (day of the year, year)

Comment: The string has to match exactly in order for the query to take.

Comment: @ChrisG It does

Comment: Hmm, try `\`Date\`` maybe. Also, shouldn't it be `Values (?, ?)` and an array with two elements?

Comment: What type of column is `Date`? Is it a VARCHAR?

Comment: Please provide an example of what `result` in your query function looks like. The format is important if you're providing column names in your query as opposed to just using `SET` and providing an object with keys that match your field names.

Comment: @ChrisG longtext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I needed to change from Longtext to charvar in mysql

Comment: ... why are you storing dates as text at all? Use [DATE or DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)